# android studio emulator not internet connectivity

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Even I open the emulator as -dns-server 8.8.8.8, there is still no internet connectivity in the android studio emulator.

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

When I ping to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
generic_x86_arm:/ $ `ping www.google.com`
PING [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (64.233.189.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
No response from here.

If I want to search module by drozer.

```
module search -d
```

There was a problem accessing one-or-more of the remote repositories.

Make sure that you have a working network connection.
But I can access the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) website in the emulator UI directly.**

Comment: Did you restart the emulator after setting the dns server as 8.8.8.8?